# how to check the box automatically when two cell values are checked

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have two sheets in sheet1 there is a checkbox for Assign grades which i only wanted to be checked automatically if the giving three check boxes (Math physics chemistry) in another sheet2 are checked, if any of the checked box in sheet2 are not checked then I do not check the assign value [theses are two separate sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JCSM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this macro works

```
Private Sub CHECKBOXES()
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).CHECKBOXES("Check Box 1").Value = xlOn And ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).CHECKBOXES("Check Box 2").Value = xlOn And ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).CHECKBOXES("Check Box 3").Value = xlOn Then
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).CHECKBOXES("Check Box 1").Value = xlOn
Else
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).CHECKBOXES("Check Box 1").Value = xlOff
End If
End Sub
```

Just need to save the macro and run it when you want.

Comment: What is there is one more check box added in  sheet1 (i.e compulsory course) and few more subjects added in sheet 2 (i.e history, statistics). and the compulsory check box have to be checked if the history and statistics are check?

Comment: Same algorithm logic: 

Add another if to function:
Example:
`If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).CHECKBOXES("Check Box history").Value = xlOn And ...[statistics etc] Then
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).CHECKBOXES("Check Box compulsory").Value = xlOn`

By the way if you have different user forms with checkboxes you can iterate them o other controls.

`For Each ctrl In Me.myform.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
        ctrl.Enabled = True / false
        ctrl.Value = True / false
    End If
Next ctrl`